# Eagle cad, choosing mm as default

Tags: eaglecad

Is there a way to set mili meter as default in Eagle cad? It resets to metric to inches every time I open a board file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EAGLE stores the grid setting within each board file, so when you open any board, you get the grid settings used last time you saved this board.

However, it is possible to configure EAGLE with custom values, which are used whenever you create a new board.
Within the EAGLE installation directory, there is the file `scr/eagle.scr`, which looks like this:

```
BRD:
MENU '[designlink22.png] Search and order : Run designlink-order.ulp -general;'\
     '[pcb-service.png] PCB Service : Run pcb-service.ulp;'\
     '[idf-3d.png] Export to IDF 3D format: Run eagleidfexporter.ulp;'\
GRID INCH
GRID 1
;




SCH:
Grid Default;
Change Width 0.006in;
MENU '[designlink22.png] Search and order {\
                                          General : Run designlink-order.ulp -general; |\
                                          Schematic : Run designlink-order.ulp; \
                                          }'\
;
```

It contains several sections for several windows (my snippet shows only `BRD` and `SCH` for board an schematic).
I've added two lines to the `BRD` section to set the grid unit to inch and step width to 1 and proved that I indeed get a 1" grid for new boards. (EAGLE 7.4.0)
Possible units are:

`GRID MM` (Millimeter)
`GRID MIC` (Micrometer)
`GRID MM`
`GRID MIL`